# Easiest way to create interactive simulated desktop app in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I'm creating a training lab for a desktop application.

Basically it'll be a series of screenshots with hotspots, when the user clicks in the right spot it advances to the next screenshot. There will also be some simple text input, so a textbox will need be overlaid over some of the screenshots. The logic is simply if the user enters the right thing they get to move to the next screen.

Adobe Captivate or good old timeline-based Flash is great for creating stuff like this. But this project has to be Silverlight. I considered using Captivate along with a swf to silverlight converter, but I believe those converters only support animations not logic.

The question is: what is the easiest way to create this type of thing in Silverlight? Can Expression Blend do it? Other alternatives? Ideally little programming is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend is great for this, you may also want to try using Sketchflow to prototype it quickly http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx

Using Expression Blend's behaviours and storyboards makes it easy to create an application with no code in no time.